# How to store userid in session using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to store user id in session so that I can use in other pages?

My code is as follows

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO

Private Sub cmdlogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    cnn.Open()

    Dim sqlcomm2 As New SqlCommand("Select * from Users where userid='" & txtuserid.Text & "'", cnn)
    Dim r2 As SqlDataReader = sqlcomm2.ExecuteReader()
    While r2.Read
        Dim UserId1 As String = Trim(UCase(CStr(r2("UserId"))))
        Dim Password As String = Trim(UCase(CStr(r2("Password"))))
        Dim username As String = CStr(r2("Name"))

        Session("User") = UserId1
        Session("Password") = Password

        'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("item")

    End While
    r2.Close()
```

but its showing error as:

> session is not declared

Answer (score 8):

You get this error when compiling your application:

Name 'session' is not declared ...

This generally occurs when using session variables in a code customization and your compiler is not able to find the session variable class.

Specify the full path of the session variable.  If you cannot access the Session class directly, you may need to specify its full path as follows:

In VB.NET, to access a value:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“MyVariable”)
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“MyVariable”).ToString()
```

In VB.NET, to set a value:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“MyVariable”) = “NewValue”
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. I tried given code also its showing HttpContext is not a member of web.

Comment: Try manually referencing System.Web through "Add reference".Right click on your application at solution explorer then select add reference,then in .net tab select system.web..

Comment: I checked in reference system.web.httpcontext is not there

Comment: Did it work or found any other solutions.If other you can post here.so that it will be helpful for others..

Comment: not other same add system.web in reference.one more doubt is how to goto next page in vb.net i tried response.redirect("Form2.vb") but it showing response is not declared. please help me. thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35905/discussion-between-user1702346-and-upvote-markanswer)

Comment: Sasidharan, than you for your post. This helped me for some my complex task.